# Apache htaccess to rewrite up one directory level

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen this asked before and people provide answers, but none of them seem to work.
I'm trying to rewrite the URL so any request to /whatever show as /.
I don't want the location of the files to change, just the URL.
For example, if someone types in:

```
Http://www.mysite.com/whatever ( the files are located at /docroot/whatever )
I want the URL to show http://www.mysite.com/
```

In my htaccess ( placed in /docroot , not /docroot/whatever ) I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^whatever/(.+)$   /$1 [L]
```

What's happening is the URL is staying , but the server is looking for the files /docroot .

That's the opposite of what I need, I need the URL to be  , with the server looking for the files in /docroot/whatever .

Comment: You can't, if you want your url to stay Http://www.mysite.com/, try ajax

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have it backwards.

- If you want the root URIs to be mapped to DOCROOT/whatever then you need to do an internal redirect in Apache.
- If you receive an external request for `http://www.mysite.com/whatever` and want the client to use the root URI then you need to do an external (301) redirect.
- You also need to make sure that you don't end up in an infinite loop.

The following lines will do this for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond   %{ENV:REDIRECT_END}  !^1 
RewriteRule   ^whatever/(.+)$  $1               [R=301,L]

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/whatever
RewriteRule   ^(.+)$           whatever/$1      [E=END:1,L]
```

In the second rule, the `E=END:1` sets the env variable END to 1, and after the internal redirect, this becomes REDIRECT_END.  The first cond stops, say /fred -> /whatever/fred -> (301) /fred -- which will cause the browser to barf.

Also start with 302s and when you've got the rules working switch to 301s -- since the client browser will cache 301s which makes a bugger of debugging these rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# change the browser's URL address bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /whatever($|\ )
RewriteRule ^whatever / [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite / back to whatever
RewriteRule ^$ /whatever [L]
```